# How do I install Sherpa into python?

Tags: python, package

I have found some install instructions, but I am still having trouble installing Sherpa (Python 2.7)

Here is the official link: https://github.com/sherpa/sherpa#how-to-install-sherpa

I already have Anaconda installed and the instructions state:

If you have Anaconda already installed on your system you can use it to seamlessly install Sherpa.

First you need to add the Sherpa channel to your configuration, and then install Sherpa:

```
$ conda config --add channels https://conda.anaconda.org/sherpa
$ conda install sherpa
```

I open up the Anaconda command prompt and complete these steps, but I am still confused. I am sorry if this question makes no sense or is not clear. I have never installed a package before on python. Can someone be able to clarify this for me or give me more detailed steps on how to install Sherpa? I have no idea what the configuration is in where I need to add a channel!

Comment: That should have added the channel,  Are you sure sherpa isn't installed?  How do you know?  Where there errors when you ran `conda install sherpa` ?

Comment: I am fairly certain Sherpa is not installed. I only heard about it today. This is my first time using the console. I am just so confused. I made simple codes using Spyder. This is all new to me.

Comment: So, I ran those two lines in a console (taking out "$" since it did not work with it) and got the error:  Fetching package metadata ...........
Solving package specifications: .
Error: Package missing in current win-64 channels:
  - sherpa

Close matches found; did you mean one of these?

    sherpa: sherpatest

You can search for packages on anaconda.org with

    anaconda search -t conda sherpa

Comment: Ah.  That explains things.  Sherpa's github page says it's available for Linux and Mac OS, but is silent on building or installing it on windows.  I suspect it isn't supported on windows, so you may need to use something else.  Kudos on getting the commands run on windows - many folks w/o linux or Mac experience don't realize that the $ is the shell prompt, and get stuck there.